# How do you identify CSS Selectors when inspecting HTML code?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, nodes, rvest

I'm trying to web scrape housing data using the rvest package, but I'm having difficulty identifying html nodes. My *(generic)* R code is as follows:

```
housing_wp <- read_html("webpage")

address <- housing_wp %>%
   html_nodes("a.unhideListingLink") %>%
   html_text()

address
```

---

The html code inspected is in the following link that contains the data I am trying to input into a table in R. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnWLx.png]

Comment: Have you tried the Selector Gadget extension? Available for Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: It might also be easier if you provided the url in question, and let us know what you want to scrape.

Comment: I've seen the gadet, I just didn't want to go through an extension. I didn't post the site because it is through a private MLS site (multiple listing software) so I gained access through a broker I am working with.

Comment: @awaji98 it looks like the issue lies in the read_html function because when I html_text(url), I can't see the data I'm trying to parce